# How to setup UIView in a nib/xib to get background colour different in runtime but not interface builder

Tags: swift, interface-builder, xib, nib, uibackgroundcolor

I'm building reusable views in xib/nib files and I have some view that need to render .clear during runtime but... My superviews that will be presenting these nibs are dark and therefore when I design these nibs they have a white background and its hard to see my text and other controls on these views.

In other, is it possible to have a background colour black for example in the interface builder and at runtime they are clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `User defined Runtime attribute` from the inspector on your view controller in storyboard to adjust your background color on runtime.

[image: User Defined Runtime Attributes screenshot]

Note: The key path is `backgroundColor`

Or just set the backgroundColor in `awakeFromNib()`. This function get's called once the nib has been loaded.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    backgroundColor = .blue
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. The user defined runtime attribute is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I couldn't use the awakeFromNib() function to do that since I have an @IBDesignable class and it loads whatever I put in the awakeFromNib() function also in the Interface Builder and my view became transparent again and I had the same problem.